# Environment in a customized model of the institutions Brazilian

Tags: environments

I am looking to define an environment in a customized model of the institutions here in Brazil where the form that the file is created is different from the ones used here in the group.
These customized Brazilian models use only the file with customizations of styles and a file as a preamble but I cannot modify or add some environments.

**What I am looking for is to implement this the ambient code, below! in my file.
In the way in which the files of this customization are arranged, I cannot understand where I can put it to work.**

There are three files used in this customization.

1. The first one with the name uecetex2.sty when I open it is written in the form of the model below that I put.
2. The second file is Preambulo.tex where the preamble is, a package-only file it is not possible to add an environment or setup for it.
3. The third file is document.tex where the chapters for compilation the PDF are assembled, at the beginning of this file it calls preambulo.tex
   But it is also not possible to add environments or setups in it, because it generates the error.

In this GitHub have original files https://github.com/thiagodnf/uecetex2

**The new environment, I put in "preambulo.tex" but when compiling it accuses error**

```
%%% This file is preambulo.tex %%%%

    \documentclass[        
        a4paper,          % Tamanho da folha A4
        12pt,             % Tamanho da fonte 12pt
        chapter=TITLE,    % Todos os capitulos devem ter caixa alta
        section=TITLE,    % Todas as secoes devem ter caixa alta
        oneside,          % Usada para impressao em apenas uma face do papel
        english,          % Hifenizacoes em ingles
        spanish,          % Hifenizacoes em espanhol
        brazil            % Ultimo idioma eh o idioma padrao do documento
    ]{abntex2}
    
    
    % Importações de pacotes
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                         % Acentuação direta
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}                            % Codificação da fonte em 8 bits
    \usepackage{graphicx}                               % Inserir figuras
    \usepackage{amsfonts, amssymb, amsmath}             % Fonte e símbolos matemáticos
    \usepackage{booktabs}                               % Comandos para tabelas
    \usepackage{verbatim}                               % Texto é interpretado como escrito no documento
    \usepackage{multirow, array}                        % Múltiplas linhas e colunas em tabelas
    \usepackage{indentfirst}                            % Endenta o primeiro parágrafo de cada seção.
    \usepackage{microtype}                              % Para melhorias de justificação?
    \usepackage[portuguese,ruled,lined]{algorithm2e}    % Escrever algoritmos
    \usepackage{algorithmic}                            % Criar Algoritmos  
    %\usepackage{float}                                  % Utilizado para criação de floats
    \usepackage{amsgen}
    \usepackage{lipsum}                                 % Usar a simulação de texto Lorem Ipsum
    %\usepackage{titlesec}                               % Permite alterar os títulos do documento
    \usepackage{tocloft}                                % Permite alterar a formatação do Sumário
    \usepackage{etoolbox}                               % Usado para alterar a fonte da Section no Sumário
    \usepackage[nogroupskip,nonumberlist,acronym]{glossaries}                % Permite fazer o glossario
    \usepackage{caption}                                % Altera o comportamento da tag caption
    \usepackage[alf, abnt-emphasize=bf, bibjustif, recuo=0cm, abnt-etal-cite=2, abnt-etal-list=0]{abntex2cite}  % Citações padrão ABNT
    %\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}                      % Mantém as notas de rodapé sempre na mesma posição
    \usepackage{helvet}
    \renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}                                % Usa a fonte Arial
    \usepackage{mathptmx}                               % Usa a fonte Times New Roman                                       
    %\usepackage{lmodern}                               % Usa a fonte Latin Modern
    %\usepackage{subfig}                                % Posicionamento de figuras
    %\usepackage{scalefnt}                              % Permite redimensionar tamanho da fonte
    %\usepackage{color, colortbl}                       % Comandos de cores
    %\usepackage{lscape}                                % Permite páginas em modo "paisagem"
    %\usepackage{ae, aecompl}                           % Fontes de alta qualidade
    %\usepackage{picinpar}                              % Dispor imagens em parágrafos
    %\usepackage{latexsym}                              % Símbolos matemáticos
    %\usepackage{upgreek}                               % Fonte letras gregas
    \usepackage{appendix}                               % Gerar o apendice no final do documento
    \usepackage{paracol}                                % Criar paragrafos sem identacao
    \usepackage{lib/uecetex2}                           % Biblioteca com as normas da UECE para trabalhos academicos
    \usepackage{pdfpages}                               % Incluir pdf no documento
    \usepackage{amsmath}                                % Usar equacoes matematicas
    \usepackage{colortbl}
    % Organiza e gera a lista de abreviaturas, simbolos e glossario
    \makeglossaries
    % Gera o Indice do documento
    \makeindex
    
%This line refers to the text of comments and questions

        \NewEnviron{commentA}{}
        \newcommand\Aon{\RenewEnviron{commentA}{\color{red}\BODY}}
        \newcommand\Aoff{\RenewEnviron{commentA}{}}
        \NewEnviron{commentB}{}
        \newcommand\Bon{\RenewEnviron{commentB}{\color{blue}\BODY}}
        \newcommand\Boff{\RenewEnviron{commentB}{}}
        \NewEnviron{commentC}{}
        \newcommand\Con{\RenewEnviron{commentC}{\color{cyan}\BODY}}
        \newcommand\Coff{\RenewEnviron{commentC}{}}
        
\begin{document}
        
        \Aoff
        \Boff
        \Coff
        \begin{commentA} \lipsum[2] \end{commentA} 
        \begin{commentB} \lipsum[2] \end{commentB} 
        \begin{commentC} \lipsum[2] \end{commentC}
        \NewEnviron{commentA}{}
        \newcommand\Aon{\RenewEnviron{commentA}{\color{red}\BODY}}
        \newcommand\Aoff{\RenewEnviron{commentA}{}}
        \NewEnviron{commentB}{}
        \newcommand\Bon{\RenewEnviron{commentB}{\color{blue}\BODY}}
        \newcommand\Boff{\RenewEnviron{commentB}{}}
        \NewEnviron{commentC}{}
        \newcommand\Con{\RenewEnviron{commentC}{\color{cyan}\BODY}}
        \newcommand\Coff{\RenewEnviron{commentC}{}}

\end{document}
```

**The new environment, I put in the style sheet named uecetex2.sty but when compiling it accuses error also**

[image]

> I have no idea I can't understand what I can do to make this environment work

Comment: I don’t think I understand your question. By the way, you should format your code as a code block.

Comment: You might want to ask a native speaker to edit your question, so it’s clearer what you’re asking.

Comment: Done @Davislor Thanks !

Comment: I also don't understand exactly what the question is - mainly because there is a lot of code in it. Maybe you can reduce your code by removing everything that is not relevant for the question? Also in the first code block it seems that there is a copy-paste problem (`\begin{document}` and a few lines below it occurs twice).

Comment: Thanks @Marijn  I was able to add more information to help in understanding and see if there is any way of being able to add ambience to this customization model in the way that Brazilian institutions are using it, I also found it very different

Comment: One issue is that the `\NewEnviron` command requires the package `environ`, so you need to add `\usepackage{environ}` in your list of `\usepackage` statements.